# Set of all non- injective linear transformations a Subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Considering the set of linear transformations from V to W, given each are not injective does this mean that The set doesn’t form a Subspace? I would have thought this would be the case since the 0 vector from V could be mapped to another vector as well as the 0 vector in W? Or would this not be the case since it was given they are a set of LINEAR transformations? To be a Subspace would need the transformation to the 0 vector in W, is this prevented given they are Not injective?

Comment: Hi Marina, is there any reason you've deleted a large section of your question?

Comment: No! I thought it was just my screen acting up, it says I edited it 9 minutes ago which is odd. I will fill it in again as soon as possible.

Comment: You should be able to just roll back by going to the first revision in the little menu that has a list of previous revisions, and saving that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a subspace. For example, if you are in $\mathbb{R}^2$, consider
$$\varphi(x,y)=(x,0) \quad \text{and} \quad \psi(x,y)=(0,y)$$

Both are non-injective, but $\varphi+\psi = \mathrm{id}$ is injective.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough yet succinct response, this is perfectly clear!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: @MarinaCalder No ! Take $\varphi=id$ and $\psi=-id$ : both are surjective, but the sum $\varphi+\psi=0$ is not surjective at all :)

Comment: Right enough! Well thank you again, I think I definitely understand this now :)

Comment: It's maybe not quite right that this generalises to *every* space - for instance, if $V$ has strictly larger dimension than $W$, the non-injective linear maps are just the linear maps. Another case is if $V$ has dimension $1$, in which case to be non-injective, the map must have trivial image, so you do get a subspace. And if $\dim V = 0$, then there aren't any non-injective maps at all, so it's not a subspace because there's no identity element.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen You are right. I rather meant "if you have specific spaces, you can see if this applies", but indeed, it is useful to precise that it does not always apply.

Comment: @MarinaCalder Indeed. For the surjective case, from the moment $W \neq 0$ and there exists a surjective linear map from $V$ to $W$, then it is never a subspace (just consider $\varphi$ surjective, then $\varphi-\varphi$ is not surjective).

Comment: Yes, actually the fact that a transformation has its null space different from $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ exactly means that it is not injective.